# proxy_pass doesn't seem to resolve to upstream

Tags: nginx, proxy

I use this configuration below but somehow it doesn't proxy to the upstream.

```
upstream backend  {
    ip_hash;
    server s1.example.com;
    server s2.example.com;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://backend;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

However, if i replace to `proxy_pass http://s1.example.com`, it proxy successfully to the `s1.example.com` server.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why you think it does not work?

Comment: What is the actual error message nginx is showing (sanitized)?

Answer (score 1):

The [NGINX config says about `proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> Parameter value can contain variables. In this case, if an address is specified as a domain name, the name is searched among the described server groups, and, if not found, is determined using a resolver.

It does NOT state how the parameter handles a hostname when it's a constant/statically defined. [According to this NGINX forum post](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,215830,215832#msg-215832):

> domain names statically configured in config are only looked 
>   up once on startup (or configuration reload).

Using an `upstream` block  (as in your example) won't save you from this problem ("statically defined *hostname* is only looked up once after start/reload") unless you are using (the pay for) NGINX Plus and then you can add the `resolve` argument to the end of the nested [`server` parameter](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server).

The good news is that even in the free NGINX you can workaround the lookup problem by using variables like so:

```
upstream backend  { ... }
server {
  ...
  set $backend "backend";
  proxy_pass http://$backend;
  ...
}
```

but this introduces its own caveats. See https://github.com/DmitryFillo/nginx-proxy-pitfalls for a thorough discussion of workarounds and pitfalls to the "NGINX proxy repeat DNS resolution" problem.